# Should I start a project on Drupal 7 in 2017?

Tags: 7

I have a company intranet project that includes some features like:

- advanced user permissions
- company events calendar
- collaborative edition of nodes and workflows

Drupal 8 was interesting for me because of **OOP** and **Inline editing** of nodes (which is a huge point for the User Experience of non technician users of the company).

I tried to make a prototype with Drupal 8, but I encountered a **lot of beta modules** and some weren't even usable (Calendar module for instance).

In May 2017, Drupal 8 seems to be not as usable and stable than Drupal 7. This is why I'm tempted to use Drupal 7 for this project.

Do you think that starting a Drupal 7 project from scratch is a good choice in 2017 ?

Comment: Heck no! Drupal 8 for sure. Some modules might not be ready, I don't know but with D8 you will have much easier time to find a devleoper who can implement what you need since there is not that much drupalisms left in D8 anymore.

Comment: Definitely an opinion question here, but there are important factors to consider. D8 is moving forward steadily and is great for many sites. Your needs might be pushing the envelope a little. However if you're okay with a little work then D8 is definitely the right choice (imho)... unfortunately I can't add this as an opposing answer as the question has been moderated.  Moderators please take note that this is unfair, and exactly why opinion questions are disallowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not a coder, then D8 probably isn't ready, for the exact reasons you have run into. Major modules have not been released, and a huge majority of modules are still in beta version. Unless you have the coding skill to help fix bugs and/or to upgrade modules to D8, you will run into plenty of roadblocks. So D7 will likely be a better fit for you.